# Binary log error in mysql

Tags: mysql

When I am trying to check binary log:

```
 SHOW BINARY LOGS;
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1381 (HY000): You are not using binary logging.

How to resolve this? Can anybody help?

Comment: By any chance, are you running Amazon RDS ???

Comment: No, I am not using Amazon RDS.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Set the `log-bin` variable in your MySQL configuration file, then restart MySQL.

An example `my.cnf` (on Linux/unix) or `my.ini` (on Windows) would look like:

```
[client]
...

[mysqld]
...
log-bin=mysql-bin
---
```

Once restarted, MySQL automatically creates a new binary log (does so upon every restart).
You may also wish to look at the following variables:

```
server-id        = 1
expire_logs_days = 4
sync_binlog      = 1
```

Read details on the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html). If you're after replication setup (a primary reason for using binary logs), check out [Replication configuration checklist](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/replication-configuration-checklist).

Comment: server-id        = 1
expire_logs_days = 7
sync_binlog      = 0

Comment: Sorry, seems like your comment has been truncated. Can you re-comment or edit?

Comment: Anyway, your settings are just fine -- my own values were merely examples. Do note that on `sync_binlog=0` you are taking some risk that on power failure on master, transaction logs and binary logs go out of sync, resulting in a mismatch between master data and slave data.

Comment: On windows you NEED to end with a / to ensure that it is interpreted as a folder.

Answer (score 6):

Line

```
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

must placed above lines:

```
[mysqld_safe]

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log

pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: Nice...but please add some explanation to make it understood better.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to activate binary logging at startup

Add the following lines in /etc/my.cnf under the [mysqld] section

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=mysql-bin
expire-logs-days=7
```

Then, run this

```
service mysql restart
```

The next time you login to mysql, you will see a binary log listing and will rotate out after 7 days.

The default location of the binary logs will be `/var/lib/mysql` or where datadir is defined. If you specify a folder before the binlog name, then that folder is the location.

For example

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=/var/log/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days=7
```

### **UPDATE 2012-07-12 02:20 AM EDT**

Please restart mysql as follows and tell us if binary logging in on

```
service mysql restart --log-bin=mysql-bin
```

Comment: Please restart mysql like this : `service mysql restart --log-bin=mysql-bin`

Comment: Did you place `log-bin=mysql-bin` under the `[mysqld]` header or did you place under a different header in your my.cnf ???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13768/discussion-between-ajay-kadyan-and-rolandomysqldba)

Answer (score 0):

To enable the binary log, start the server with the --log-bin[=base_name] option.

If no base_name value is given, the default name is the value of the pid-file option (which by default is the name of host machine) followed by -bin.

If the basename is given, the server writes the file in the data directory unless the basename is given with a leading absolute path name to specify a different directory. It is recommended that you specify a basename.

Or you can directly use:

```
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

and then restart your mysql service. Then binary file will be generated. If you are using lampp on Linux machine then you will find this file in /lampp/var/mysql/mysql-bin.000001

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had the same issue after I tried to set up *my.cnf.master* and *my.cnf.slave* files and **symlink** them to *my.cnf* for master and slave, respectively. The idea was to be able to switch the machine from master to slave and back easily.

It turned out that mysqld simply did not handle the symlink as expected. **Hard-linking** the file worked (*ln my.cnf.master my.cnf*). Careful if you do something like this, as overwriting one of the hard-linked filenames could break the link and create two separate files instead (depending on the method of rewriting employed by the software you use for it).

Answer (score 0):

I've found logging will silently fail to happen even if my.cnf config is right, so you can also try re-creating your log folder.

This may be necwssary if the logs are in an odd state. (In my case, I had simply ceased logging in my.cnf and then re-enabled it, but nothing happened, probably because the existing files were not the latest updates?).

Something like this should work:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mv /var/log/mysql /tmp/mysqlold # or rm -fr if you're brave
mkdir /var/log/mysql
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
sudo service mysql start
```

**Obligatory warning:** Obviously, take care when deleting anything on a database server. This will destroy/disrupt/corrupt any replication using this database as master (though you can resume replication as a slave). That said, I believe this should be safe insofar as it doesn't delete the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

I went out of my mind with this issue on a MySQL 5.5 master running Debian. None of the above worked. Finally, I rebooted the server and logging was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

**For MariaDB users:**

I recently had the same message with my MariaDB installation. Here the syntax was slightly different to enable the binary log.

```
[mysqld]
log_bin = /path/to/logfolder/mysql-bin.log expire_logs_days = 10 max_binlog_size = 100M binlog_format = mixed
```

Restart the server after the change.