# After updating php version in XAMPP I'm facing Fatal Error in http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

For the **New Laravel project**, I need to update the **PHP** version using **XAMPP**,
After the update, the PHP version and apache folder when I start apache and MySQL from the **XAMPP control panel** this working but I open **localhost/phpmyadmin/** it shows me fatal error and doesn't show the database.

`Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You are not using binary logging in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php:199 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php(199): mysqli->query('SHOW MASTER LOG...', 0) #1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php(316): PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiMysqli->realQuery('SHOW MASTER LOG...', Object(mysqli), 1) #2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php(1869): PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->tryQuery('SHOW MASTER LOG...', 256, 1, false) #3 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Menu.php(573): PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->fetchResult('SHOW MASTER LOG...', 'Log_name', NULL, 256, 1) #4 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Menu.php(107): PhpMyAdmin\Menu->_getServerTabs() #5 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Menu.php(70): PhpMyAdmin\Menu->_getMenu() #6 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Header.php(445): PhpMyAdmin\Menu->getDisplay() #7 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Response.php(323): PhpMyAdmin\Header->getDisplay() #8 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Response.php(336): PhpMyAdmin\Response->_getDisplay() #9 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Response.php(495): PhpMyAdmin\Response->_htmlResponse() #10 [internal function]: PhpMyAdmin\Response->response() #11 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php on line 199`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binary log error in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445678/binary-log-error-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same issue and I have spent many hours trying to figure this out, so it is as simple as this.

Once you have upgraded your php. (In my case I upgraded to php 8.1.10)

- Make a copy of your phpMyAdmin folder renaming it different than the current value that it has.
- Download [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) 5.2.0 or higher.
- Unzip the file, and then copy it into your xampp folder replacing the old phpMyAdmin folder.
- Inside the new folder create the file config.inc.php and paste inside there the data that is in config.inc.php located in your old phpMyAdmin folder.
- Thats it!

Comment: Thank you so much i am facing this error "The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.
Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there."

Comment: this is due to root user 
in xampp>phpMyAdmin>config.inc.php

Answer (score 1):

I feel the main issue is that your tried to upgrade only php instead of the whole Xampp Bundle. Either you should install complete xampp again or you should upgrade phpMyAdmin manually too as this will fix the php compatibility issues.